# filter() in dplyr problem. Can't filter to make a dataset containing three characters

Tags: r, dplyr

[pic of environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZD5M.png)

I am attempting to make a new dataset from my original `monarch.data` df that consists of all variables for just three milkweed species (`Milkweed_species`).

```
library(dplyr)
three_species <- filter(milkweed.data, milkweed.data$Milkweed_species == c("Asclepias nivea","Asclepias tuberosa", "Asclepias californica"))
```

This is the code I have tried, along with other attempts and it is returning a df that only has one of the species:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lxQu.png)

What am I doing wrong/how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dplyr, you have to pass the variables in tidy format. And also, the comparison is not well formatted. Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
three_species <- filter(milkweed.data, Milkweed_species %in% c("Asclepias nivea","Asclepias tuberosa", "Asclepias californica"))
```

milkweed.data should be you original data. If, as you said, your original data is monarch.data, use this as the first argument of `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

For filtering by multiple values, you need to use `%in%` rather than `==`.

```
library(dplyr)

three_species <-
  filter(milkweed.data,
    Milkweed_species %in% c(
      "Asclepias nivea",
      "Asclepias tuberosa",
      "Asclepias californica"
    )
  )
```

**Output**

```
       Milkweed_species Trichomes Latex Toxin_amt Caterpillar_mass
1       Asclepias nivea        54    34         6                2
2    Asclepias tuberosa         1     3         2               56
3 Asclepias californica         5     1         6                2
4       Asclepias nivea         5     2         4                3
```

Essentially, for each value in `milkweed.data$Milkweed_species`, we are checking to see if it exists in your supplied list. Then, `filter` will keep only those that are `TRUE`.

```
milkweed.data$Milkweed_species %in% c("Asclepias nivea", "Asclepias tuberosa", "Asclepias californica")

#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

**Data**

```
milkweed.data <- structure(list(Milkweed_species = c("Ascelpias amplexicaulis", 
"Asclepias boliviensis", "Asclepias nivea", "Asclepias tuberosa", 
"Asclepias californica", "Asclepias nivea"), Trichomes = c(3, 
21, 54, 1, 5, 5), Latex = c(1, 5, 34, 3, 1, 2), Toxin_amt = c(3, 
1, 6, 2, 6, 4), Caterpillar_mass = c(3, 5, 2, 56, 2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```